# p x q business product sales for multiple divisions/geographies

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have a business that sells the same product in three different countries (countries $x$, $y$ and $z$).Product sales is given by price times quantity, so sales of the product in country $x$ is:
$$
s_x = p_x*q_x
$$
where $p_x$ represents the price of the product in country $x$ and $q_x$ represents the quantity sold. We also know that sales for the entire company is the sum of sales in all three countries, so:
$$
s_t = s_x + s_y + s_z
$$
which can be rewritten as:
$$
p_tq_t =p_xq_x + p_yq_y + p_zq_z
$$
I am provided the:

- total sales ($s_t$),
- sales from each country ($s_x,s_y,s_z$),
- total quantity sold for the company ($q_t$), and
- the relative pricing between each country (i.e. $p_y=0.75p_x$ and $p_z=0.5p_x$).

Do I have enough information to solve for the price and quantity sold in each country (assuming $p$ and $q$ must be positive)? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Give a numerical example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do.

There's a bit of redundancy in what you know: once you know $s_x, s_y, s_z$, you can figure out $s_t$ by summing them up, for instance.

There's also something a little mysterious: you write $p_t q_t$, and while $q_t$ makes a lot of sense, $p_t$ is ... what? It's not necessarily the price that any unit sold for. In fact, it's an "average price per unit," but seems oddly irrelevant here.

Anyhow, on with the show:

$$
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\color{red}{#1}}
$$

For relative pricing, I'm going to write
$$
p_x = \red{f_x} p_x \\
p_y = \red{f_y} p_x \\
p_z = \red{f_z} p_x
\tag{1}
\label{1}
$$
so that the $f$ values are your "relative price" factors. Obviously $f_x = 1$, but in your example, $f_y = 0.75$ and $f_z = 0.5$. I'm using "f" so that I get a more generic answer. And I'm coloring them red because we know them.

We also know *sales* for each region, and we know that
\begin{align}
\red{s_x} &= p_x q_x \\
\red{s_y} &= p_y q_y \\
\red{s_z} &= p_z q_z \\
\end{align}
which we can rewrite as
\begin{align}
\frac{\red{s_x}}{p_x} &= q_x \\
\frac{\red{s_y}}{p_y} &= q_y \\
\frac{\red{s_z}}{p_z} &= q_z 
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

Substituting in the Equation \eqref{1} forms for $p_x, p_y$ and $p_z$ in Equation \eqref{2}, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\red{s_x}}{\red{f_x}p_x} &= q_x \\
\frac{\red{s_y}}{\red{f_y}p_x} &= q_y \\
\frac{\red{s_z}}{\red{f_z}p_x} &= q_z 
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
and putting everything over a common denominator gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{\red{f_y f_z}\red{s_x}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} &= q_x \\
\frac{\red{f_x f_z}\red{s_y}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} &= q_y \\
\frac{\red{f_x f_y}\red{s_z}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} &= q_z 
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
We can sum these up to get the known total quantity $q_t$:
\begin{align}
\red{q_t} 
&= 
\frac{\red{f_y f_z}\red{s_x}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} +
\frac{\red{f_x f_z}\red{s_y}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} + 
\frac{\red{f_x f_y}\red{s_z}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x} \\ 
&= \frac{\red{f_y f_z}\red{s_x} +
\red{f_x f_z}\red{s_y} + 
\red{f_x f_y}\red{s_z}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}p_x}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by $p_x$, and dividing both by $q_t$, we arrive at
\begin{align}
p_x
&= \frac{\red{f_y f_z}\red{s_x} +
\red{f_x f_z}\red{s_y} + 
\red{f_x f_y}\red{s_z}}{\red{f_x f_y f_z}\red{q_t}}
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}
which gives us $p_x$ in terms of things we know. We can then use Equation \eqref{1} to compute $p_y$ and $p_z$ as well, and then use
Equation \eqref{2} to compute $q_x, q_y,$ and $q_z$, and we're done!

Note that by cancelling, Equation \eqref{6} can be simplified to
\begin{align} 
p_x
&= \frac{1}{q_t}\left(
 \frac{\red{s_x}}{\red{f_x}} +
 \frac{\red{s_y}}{\red{f_y}} +
 \frac{\red{s_z}}{\red{f_z}}\right)
\tag{6a}\label{6a}
\end{align}
which may suggest something useful to you, although I don't immediately see what that would be. :)

Comment: This assumes you know $q_x$, $q_y$ and $q_z$ but that is what I am trying to solve for (the quantity in each country). I am also trying to solve for the price in each country.

Comment: Right .. sorry. I don't do economic stuff, and was confused between "sales" (which means 'money') and q (which means units). I'll go back and edit/fix, assuming it's possible. :)

Comment: Fixed up to answer actual question.